# What is the name of this website

Tags: classical-latin

About a year ago I saw a list on some wiki site that listed all of the websites that are doing a computer analysis of Latin.  I've done a lot of googling but cannot find the site.  I don't think it was a Wikipedia site. Does anyone know of such a site?

Comment: What do you mean by computer analysis? But good chances you are referring to: https://wiki.digitalclassicist.org/Main_Page

Comment: Thanks, I thinks that's the site.  By computer analysis, I mean something that analyzes text using computers, I'm joking but I just couldn't resist.

Comment: @d_e You should post that as an answer (and bobsmith76 should accept it using the tick button) so the question can be marked as resolved.